# Where can I download Oracle 9i Personal Edition for Linux (or Windows 7)

Tags: oracle

Where can I download Oracle 9i Personal Edition for Linux (or Windows 7)? Is it still available anywhere? Oracle's website keeps redirecting to later editions.

Answer (score 1):

Personal Edition is a Windows only option, so there isn't a Linux option for any version.

If you have a valid, current Oracle support contract, you should be able to get Oracle 9iR2 (and patches) from [Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 9i is obsolete, and isn't certified for Windows 7. Any particular reason you want to download 9i ?

Get the [latest version from OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/index.html). If its for personal use, you can also get [Oracle 10g Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/xe/index.html).